# VSCode messed debugging, watches, variables, evaluation with python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I just noticed my VSCode debugger stopped working. I messed it up by accident or maybe the update changed something. Either way, I have no clue what to change to get it working.

What doesn't work is Variable list during debugging - it is always empty. Watches show as *not available*, calls tack only displays  *paused on breakpoint*. Breakpoints work but stepping over lines is not available. Also, trying to evaluate a piece of code gives:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/█/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2018.10.1/pythonFiles/experimental/ptvsd/ptvsd/wrapper.py", line 1339, in done
    fut.result()
  File "/home/█/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2018.10.1/pythonFiles/experimental/ptvsd/ptvsd/futures.py", line 40, in result
    reraise(self._exc_info)
  File "/home/█/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2018.10.1/pythonFiles/experimental/ptvsd/ptvsd/futures.py", line 149, in callback
    x = next(it)
  File "/home/█/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2018.10.1/pythonFiles/experimental/ptvsd/ptvsd/wrapper.py", line 1957, in on_evaluate
    vsc_fid = int(args['frameId'])
KeyError: 'frameId'
```

I suppose it is a matter of some basic config but I can't find a solution

Comment: Please file a bug at https://github.com/microsoft/ptvsd and include any code you can to help reproduce this.

Comment: @BrettCannon I identified 2 problems: 1. Linux Mint software manager distributes an erratic version of VSCode, changing back to .deb from VS-page helped with KeyError I mentioned. 2. Debugging doesnt work with conda environment (not debugging itself, but watches/variables/ignoring breakpoints). Using virtualenv or no env for debugging pieces of code is a workaround for me. I will reproduce the problem later.